# get array from text android java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm french so sorry for my english, I need some help, I'm trying to have a Array ( or ArrayList ) from my text file who is like this :

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,2,2
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I've already try this :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> multi=new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> line=new ArrayList();
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("level/world1/w1-1.txt"), "UTF-8"));
        String mLine = reader.readLine();

        while (mLine != null) {
            mLine = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

But I don't know how to put my mLine in my multi Array :/

Thank you for your help ! :)

Comment: it's a 2 dimensionnal array

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've already written the code to read the file correctly, so really your question is about how to parse a comma-delimited `String` into a series of `Integer` objects and store them in a `List` in an efficient manner.

Java already has nice tools for doing simple text parsing, and in this case using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) seems like a good fit.

Try something like this for your inner loop:

```
    while (mLine != null) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(mLine);  // create a Scanner for each line
        sc.useDelimiter(",");             // parse the line for tokens delimited by commas

        ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<>();
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            inner.add(sc.nextInt());      // add each number found to the inner list
        }
        multi.add(inner);                 // add the inner list to the outer list

        sc.close();

        mLine = reader.readLine();
    }
```

Notice that `Scanner` allows you to set the delimiter you want to parse by, and has several built-in types that it knows about, so you won't need to do any intermediate `String` creation or type casting.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList();

BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(...);
    String line = null;
    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(",");
        List<Integer> row = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            row.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]));
        }
        matrix.add(row);
    }
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

I would recommend to include the number of files and columns in the very first line of the file. Something like:

```
30,25
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
(...)
```

Then you can read it and create an int[][] multi-array accordingly (and hence improve memory usage).